# Llamar a conexión a bd hecha en java desde jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Quiero llamar a mi conexión a la bd `MySql` que la tengo en una clase java desde un `jsp` utilizando código java.

**Clase Conexion.java**

```
public class Conexion {

    private static Connection cnx = null;

    public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       if (cnx == null) {
          try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/deliveryTrackingBD", "root", "root");
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());   
          }
       }
       return cnx;
    }
}
```

**Clase Consulta.java**

```
public class Consulta {

    private final String tabla;
    private final Connection cnx;

    public Consulta(String tabla) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        this.tabla = tabla;
        this.cnx = Conexion.obtener();
    }

    public ResultSet recuperarPorId(int id) throws SQLException {
       Pedido pedido = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       try{
          PreparedStatement consulta = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + this.tabla + " WHERE Id = ?" );
          consulta.setInt(1, id);
           rs = consulta.executeQuery();
       }
       catch(SQLException ex){
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());    
       }
       return rs;
    }
}
```

En el **jsp** tengo esto:

```
<%
     int id = 12;
     Consulta cons = new Consulta("pedido");
     String dir = null;
     Pedido ped = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     try {
         rs = cons.recuperarPorId(id);
         while(rs.next()){
             ped = new Pedido(rs.getString("descripcion"), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("precio")), rs.getString("direccion"), (rs.getString("fechaHora")), rs.getString("comentario"), rs.getString("idEstado"), rs.getString("idRepartidor"));
         }
         dir = ped.getDireccion();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
 %>
 <script>
        geocoding('<%=dir%>');
 </script>
```

Es un proyecto java web application.
Al ejecutarlo me tira error (que no me dice nada), pero creo yo que es al new Consulta porque dentro hace la conexión.
El error dice:

> C:\Users\juanm\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\appRepartidores\nbproject\build-impl.xml:874:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\juanm\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\appRepartidores\nbproject\build-impl.xml:296:
>   Cancelled by user. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Embeber código Java en los JSPs se considera actualmente una **mala práctica**. Hay una discusión interesante sobre este tema [aquí](http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_enterprise/jsp_sin_scriplets#comment-7687).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que sucede cuando se abre un proyecto viejo con un `netbeans` moderno y que `netbeans` no es capaz de actualizar correctamente el fichero **build-impl.xml.**

Ir al fichero  `build-impl.xml` , Linea 829 y Eliminar la opción `excludeFromCopy` , luego compilar nuevamente.

> Bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231468

**Variable DIR=Null**

Cambiar `While` por un `if`

```
if (resultSet.next() ){
   ped = new Pedido(rs.getString("descripcion"), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("precio")), 
    rs.getString("direccion"), (rs.getString("fechaHora")), rs.getString("comentario"),
    rs.getString("idEstado"), rs.getString("idRepartidor"));
 }
 dir = ped.getDireccion();
```

Comment: Gracias! ahora si compila, pero otra consulta, la variable dir me queda null, no esta trayendo de la bd, sabes por que?

Comment: Verificó que en su base datos el registro consultado con el id 12, tenga valor? antes de `dir = ped.getDireccion();` imprimir el objeto `System.out.println(ped.toString());` solo para comprobar. no es necesario el `while(rs.next())` cuando solo leerá un registro devuelto.

Comment: @JuanManuel no entiendo el uso de `while`ahi ..  nunca sale del bucle no? y si no entra, `ped` no se inicializa y `dir` no deja de ser `null`

Comment: Si tiene valor el id 12, solo me trae un registro porque hay uno solo con ese id. No es necesario while si me trae un solo registro?

Comment: @JuanManuel [`.next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) devuelve `true` si la fila es valida y `false` si no hay mas filas. Yo pondria un `If` en vez de un `while` al menos como entiendo que funciona tu aplicacion

Comment: @lois6b era poner el `If`, Gracias!!

Comment: @DarkFenix ese comentario de "`No Hay datos devueltos`" no lo veo muy intuitivo. si devuelve false es que no hay mas filas, no que esa fila no esté bien

Comment: @DarkFenix Gracias! era eso si.

Comment: @lois6b Sí entra a ese `if ` no hay datos devueltos (no existe ninguna fila), si fuese un `while` es para verificar lo que dices "No hay más filas", Juan si te ayudó marcar mi respuesta como aceptada. Gracias

Comment: @DarkFenix no, si entra en ese IF tuyo, es porque el valor de next() es false, por lo que no hay más filas, no que no hay datos devueltos. pero en la fila que está si hay datos. tiene que comprobar que el `rs!=null`

Comment: @lois6b Tiene usted Razón. error mio. Gracias